# Running Convert-MsolDomainToStandard to de-federate

Tags: powershell, office365, azure-active-directory, adfs, azure-powershell

We're about to de-federate our Office365 domain from using adfs2.0 to using passwords sync'd with Azure AD Sync.

We understand the process to need us to run Convert-MsolDomainToStandard, and then force a re-sync of our password with Azure AD Sync. All good so far.

First question. What powershell can we run to confirm that all our passwords are re-syncing OK on the Azure/365 side? For example, can we get the last password sync time for each user? (not last password change time - that's different!) We really need confidence to pull the trigger on this with 18,000 users.

Second question. After we run this, what powershell can we run to ensure all users have been de-federated properly? A belts and braces check that they've all been correctly updated. I've seen that a lot of people de-federating have had to use Convert-MsolFederatedUser for some users after Convert-MsolDomainToStandard crashed out. What attributes would mark an Azure user as using federated logon rather than managed?

Answer (score 0):

You can review the Application Event log to check if the password sync for every federated user is successful, as well as the sync time.

The Event ID 650 indicates that the password sync process started, and the Event ID 657 will show you users whose password sync is successful or not.

[image]

For the second question, I haven't found such powershell comlet to query if the users have been de-federated or not. However, when using the following cmdlet, you will get the users listed in the password.txt, which contains each federated users' temporary password. If you run the following cmdlet again, the users who have already been converted to de-federated will not be issued a new password, the temporary password column will be changed to N/A after the full password sync is completed. So, you can confirm if a user is de-federated or not based on this by examining the password files.
**Convert-MsolDomainToStandard -DomainName *federated Domain name* -SkipUserConversion $false -PasswordFile c:\password.txt**

Finally, more references around this can be found here:[[1]](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/kb/2855271) and [[2]](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17857.dirsync-how-to-switch-from-single-sign-on-to-password-sync.aspx).